# Visual Studio Installer Projects not updating dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-installer

I'm using Visual Studio Installer Projects Extension to create the installer for my program in Visual Studio 2013. Everything, the program and the installer projects, has been upgraded from Visual Studio 2008, where it worked pretty well.

The problem I'm having is that the installer does not update the "Detected Dependencies" section, even if I manually tell it to, so the dlls the main program depends on (my own dlls, or CRT, MFC, etc) are not included.

If I mess around with the projects (manually add some dll to the installer, or change the "Optimized for..." parameter, exclude something I don't need, you name it), I sometimes get it to update, normally once, but the next time I run it, they are gone again.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've had multiple problems with the VS2015 version regarding detected dependencies and excluded files, which may still be apparent in the VS2013 version.

I would explicitly include all your dependencies, and ship MFC/CRT using vcredist.exe as a pre boostrapper package.

See [this connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1900756), (and upvote if you can!) highlighting my woes with the dependencies feature.

Comment: Your "this connect issue" link is broken...

Comment: @Jazimov cheers - We spent 8 weeks moving our installers to Wix now. It's big learning curve, but now, adding a file is a 1 minute job with 100% expected impact! Unlike before.